# How to update RealmObject inside RealmObject properties?

Tags: android, realm, insert-update

```
Message extends RealmObject{
Attachment attachment;
}

Attachment extends RealmObject{
int state;
}
```

I want to update state inside Attachment. I followed a path like this:

```
RealmResults<Message> allMessages = mRealm.where(Message.class)
                .isNotNull("attachment")
                .in("attachment.state", new Integer[]{INTERRUPTED,PENDING})
                .findAll();

if (allMessages != null && allMessages.size() > 0) {
    for (Message message : allMessages) {
        Attachment attachment = message.getAttachment();
        attachment.setState(IDLE);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to update state via direct Attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um.

```
try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
        RealmResults<Attachment> attachments = realm.where(Attachment.class)
           .in("state", new Integer[]{INTERRUPTED,PENDING})
           .findAll();
        for(Attachment attachment: attachments) {
            attachment.setState(IDLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there find of all attachments inside Message object? 

And the where clause is true?
`RealmResults<Attachment> attachments = realm.where(Attachment.class)
.in("attachment.state", new Integer[]{
                    INTERRUPTED,PENDING}).findAll();`

Comment: You might want to explain the following things: 1.) why isn't Attachment.state just a field inside Message called `attachmentState` and 2.) why can Attachment exist that doesn't belong to a Message? - - - your schema is probably incomplete so we can't have a proper view of what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Some Message objects have only text, some objects have attachment. Attachments have progress states.

Comment: Does it have any other field than `progressState`?

Comment: why do we use try @EpicPandaForce?

Comment: Because I can't be sure what thread your `mRealm` was created on :D

Comment: thank you ) please help me another new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646502/how-should-i-use-realm-in-realmadapters

Comment: I can't know why you have Realm open from multiple processes so I cannot answer that.

Comment: I used all realm operations in realmThread but adapters' realm operations are only working in main thread. Therefore realm operations are conflicts. How can I manage them?

Comment: Process has nothing to do with *threads*. I think you are most likely opening Realm in `Application.onCreate()` and so you try to open Realm in your either Crashlytics background process or in Leakcanary background process

Comment: Yes I'm opening realm in `Application.onCreate()`. What should I do?

Comment: I moved this kind of "Realm opening" to `BaseActivity.onCreate()` personally

Comment: I have many background process which has used realm operations. Only realm opening to `activity.onCreate` that not useful for me.  I can't understand Crashlytics or Leakcanary background processes. Can you explain that?

Comment: I don't know what you need multiple processes for, and I do not see your configuration for it. It is also not related to this comment section, so I'll stop responding regarding that here. **You** are probably thinking of background *threads*, so no, all you need to do is move any initialization that does DB writes to be "started off" by the `BaseActivity` only once on start-up in `onCreate()` when a `static boolean` flag is `false` (which you set to `true` once you started the tasks).

Comment: I don't use activity when some realm operations. Therefore I can't use your proposal : `activity.onCreate ``

please comment my this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646502/how-should-i-use-realm-in-realmadapters

Please help me.

Comment: Then use `try(Realm realm = Realm.getInstance...`